# Confusion with textbook sentence on unsized array initialization C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I am reading a book on C++ programming. I encountered a sentence from the book that says: "Besides being less tedious, the unsized array initialization method allows you to change any of the strings without the fear of accidentally forgetting to resize the array." When I wrote some code to test that sentence and then ran the code at the end of execution I receive an error that the .exe has stopped working. And with other code shown in my question it gives an incompatible type error i.e. the dimensions of the new string don't match the dimensions of the char array.

So I tested the sentence to see if my interpretation of it was correct. See my code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[] = "";
    s = "Hello, my name is Mickey Mouse.";
    cout << s << endl;
    s = "Hello, my name is Mickey Mouse. I am 83 years old."
    cout << s << endl;

}
```

Next code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[] = "";
    cout << "Enter a string" << endl;
    cin.getline(s, 50);
    cout << s;
    cout << "How old are you" << endl;
    cin.getline(s, 50);
    cout << s;
}
```

I expected the program to run successfully but instead it crashes.

Comment: `char s[] = "";` is the same as `char s[1] = {'\0'};` So trying to copy anything into it larger than one byte is an error.

Comment: What compiler? The first code snippet is invalid and fails for me with both GCC 7.4 and VS2019.

Comment: I also saw that when I was browsing the web. I'm trying to get the correct interpretation of the sentence from the text shown in quotes in the upper most paragraph of the question.

Comment: I am using the GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: I am also using code blocks.

Comment: Was the book referring to something like: `char s[] = "Hello, my name is Mickey Mouse.";`?

Comment: Which version? On Linux?

Comment: That's not how you assign to an array.

Comment: Don't use C-style arrays in new code unless you really *have to* for some obscure reason. Use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for arrays where the size is known at compile time and [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) when the size needs to be dynamic at run-time. There's *almost never* a reason to reach for the old-school C array - it's more pain than gain - the `std::array` abstraction is super convenient and really thin, it compiles away completely in optimized builds. And if you need more, you basically need `std::vector`.

Comment: The textbook had as an example: char e1[] = "www.weather.com"; Thereafter it mentioned the sentence.

Comment: Ok, it's just telling you that you can avoid entering the size of the array. `char e1[16] = "www.weather.com";` The compiler will calculate the `16` for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example  you are overwriting a large piece of the stack, which will probably crash, although as undefined behaviour may have other unexpected results.

`char s[] = "";` is the same as `char s[1] = {'\0'};`, which contains just a single element, the null character. The book is simply saying in this case it determines the size for you and copies it to the stack.

Then when you use `cin.getline(s, 50);` and tell it that it is actually 50 characters long, it may write past the end of the array and overwrite other things that the compiler placed on the stack causing corruption.

Often for things like `getline` if you do have a stack allocated array, `sizeof` can be used to determine the size in a safe way that will accommodate future changes.

```
cin.getline(s, sizeof(s));
```

But in C++, it is almost always better to use `std::string` for strings, and either `std::vector` for dynamically sized arrays, or `std::array` for ones of a fixed size. As well as supporting a lot more features directly, they also handle memory management and make it easier to avoid many common errors.

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```